# Facebook API version detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook

We recently received this alert from Facebook on our Unity App.

Your app has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0, which will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday, August 8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid potential broken experiences.

The SDK version is 6.2.2 which should be on API 2.2 - 2.4.

These are the APIs/Properties I'm using:

FB.Init(OnFbInit, OnHideUnity);
FB.API("/me?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,GotFBData);
FB.IsLoggedIn;
FB.UserId
FB.AccessToken
FB.Login

Why is Facebook saying we are using API 2.0? Is it safe to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the `/me?fields=name` call there is probably another call you are using in some legacy code perhaps. Consider using [API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/) you can find out more information about it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/api-upgrade-tool/

Comment: Check out the alert I get on Facebook dev page.  

![Facebook API Alert](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9385978/FacebookAPIs.PNG).

It looks like its the /me?fields=name right?

Answer (score 0):

Just recently one dude found an answer to this. Looks like Facebook has a bug where it mistakenly assumes an app is using v2.0. Nevertheless, I think it won't hurt to check if an app is properly updated.

[Facebook Developer Bug page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1634445133540643/)

[Unity Answers URL](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1206408/facebook-developer-alert-recent-api-calls-to-graph.html)